# Is shared memory persistent from one kernel launch to another?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

When trying to find whether shared memory can be accessed by multiple kernels, I have found that sometimes the data in shared memory are still there when accessing by another kernel, but sometimes not. What's more, when debugging the program with cuda-gdb, the data written in shared memory by the previous kernel can be ALWAYS read by the next kernels.

The following is a piece of test code, with 2 GPUs.

```
    extern __shared__ double f_ds[];
    __global__ void kernel_writeToSharedMem(double* f_dev, int spd_x)
    {
       int tid_dev_x = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x);
       int tid_dev_y = (blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y);
       int tid_dev = tid_dev_y* spd_x + tid_dev_x;
       
       if(tid_dev < blockDim.x * blockDim.y * gridDim.x*gridDim.y)
          f_ds[threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x] = 0.12345;
       __syncthreads()
    }

  __global__ void kernel_readFromSharedMem(double *f_dev, int dev_no, int spd_x)
    {
       int tid_dev_x = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x);
       int tid_dev_y = (blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y);
       int tid_dev = tid_dev_y* spd_x + tid_dev_x;
      
       if(tid_dev < blockDim.x * blockDim.y * gridDim.x*gridDim.y)
         {
           f_dev[tid_dev] = f_ds[threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x];
           printf("threadID %d in dev [%d] is having number %f\n",
                   tid_dev,dev_no,f_ds[threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x]);
         }
       __syncthreads();
     }


    int main()
    {
     ...

       dim3 block_size(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);
       im3 grid_size(spd_x/BLOCK_SIZE,spd_y/BLOCK_SIZE);
       for(int i = 0; i < ngpus; i++)
         {
           cudaSetDevice(i);
           kernel_writeToSharedMem<<<grid_size,block_size,sizeof(double)*BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE,stream[i]>>>(f_dev[i],spd_x);
           cudaDeviceSynchronize();
           cudaThreadSynchronize();
          }
        for(int i = 0; i < ngpus; i++)
         {
           cudaSetDevice(i);
           kernel_reaFromSharedMem<<<grid_size,block_size,sizeof(double)*BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE,stream[i]>>>(f_dev[i], int i, spd_x);
           cudaDeviceSynchronize();
           cudaThreadSynchronize();
          }
      ...
    }
```

Four situations occurred after running the program:

1. Device 0 are 0.12345 but device 1 are 0;
2. Device 0 are 0 but device 1 are 0.12345;
3. Device 0 and device 1 are all 0;
4. Device 0 and device 1 are all 0.12345.

When running in cuda-gdb 4) is always the case.

Does this indicate that the shared memory's persistent is only one kernel? Would shared memory only be cleared or freed after one kernel **occasionally**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared memory is guaranteed to only have scope for the life of the block to which it is assigned. Any attempt to re-use shared memory from block to block or kernel launch to kernel launch is completely undefined behaviour and should *never* be relied in a sane code design.